# aiohttp lambda in loop.start_server() method

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand primer below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    f = loop.create_server(
    lambda:     HttpRequestHandler(debug=True, keep_alive=75),
    '0.0.0.0', '8080')
    srv = loop.run_until_complete(f)
    print('serving on', srv.sockets[0].getsockname())
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Why there is lambda nottation in asyncio.create_server method? From asyncio docs, this method accept class/function as entry point.
If its attemt to initiate class and pass initialized instance to loop, then im totally lost, because i have strange behavion, **init** method of HttpRequestHandler invokes every request:

```
class     HttpRequestHandler(aiohttp.server.ServerHttpProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        print(id(self))
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understood:
all classes with HttpServerProtocol parent is callback, initialized every single request. To save states between request, or process any agregate logic we need new object:

def Process(): 
        def **init**(self, loop):
            #instance variables self.loop=loop etc
        @asyncio.coroutine
        def serve(self):
            a = asyncio.async(self.FirstMethod(), loop=self.loop)
            b = asyncio.async(self.SecondMethod(), loop=self.loop)
            yield from asyncio.gather(*[a,b])

pass our Logic class instance  to Proto class and add serve coroutine method to execution like: loop.run_until_complete(protoInstance.serve). 
It works fine for me.